# « Le souhait de » vs. « le souhait à »

Tags: prépositions, constructions

Quelle est la forme correcte pour exprimer le souhait et pourquoi ?

Par exemple laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte :

1. J'aimerais exprimer mon souhait *à* comprendre la différence.
2. J'aimerais exprimer mon souhait *de* comprendre la différence.

Je pense que la deuxième est correcte.
Merci d'avance

Comment: Feelew Why did you rollback to first version ?

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble Please excuse me for this. I had approved your correction since I thought it was a good idea, but Laure had refused it before me and the argument for the refusal seemed reasonable. Please have a look at the discussion [there](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679/modification-refus%c3%a9e-par-moi-mais-accept%c3%a9e-%c3%a0-la-fin).

Comment: I think it's the autocorrect more than the QWERTY keyboard. ("la" changed to "LA" for example). If you're on mobile, you can add a French keyboard, it's really easy to setup, and it helps avoiding a lot of errors and saves time.

Answer (score 3):

The correct preposition to use in that case is ***de*** and it is followed by the infinitive of the verb.

> J'aimerais exprimer mon souhait de comprendre la différence.

Note that in French we tend to use the possessive adjective less often in such cases and we'd rather use the definite article.

> J'aimerais exprimer le souhait de comprendre la différence.

> Il a exprimé le souhait d'améliorer son français.